# What does $A \rightarrow B$ in set theory and database represent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm not pretty sure about how good I understood the explanation our teacher provide when we delve in fundamentals of set theory:

*(1) **A** uniquely identifies **B**, which subsequently means that any unique tuple **A** has could be used in searching for an associated member/tuple/item of **B***.

Moreover, the "mathematical" expression could be laid down as follows:

$
A \rightarrow B
$

s.t. for every tuple **t1**, **t2** which belong to the relational schema **r** we could say: t1[A] != t2[A] => t1[B] = t2[B]

**The question:**
What does $A \rightarrow B$ in set theory and database represent? (1)

Thank you in advance and for any incoherence or inaccuracy in text don't retain yourself from rising/flagging the inconveniences.

Comment: Hello! The formatting of this post looks a bit unfortunate. Did you know that putting asterisk makes italic, and two asterisks a bold font?

Comment: ops...
No, I haven't.
Let me settle this issue.

Comment: You probably will be better looking at where they discuss relational calculus https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791399/suggested-resources-for-self-teaching-relational-algebra-calculus

Comment: The "$\to$" symbol has many meanings in mathematics, depending on the context. Without further details, I would read " t1[A] != t2[A] => t1[B] = t2[B]" simply as "if  t1[A] $\ne$ t2[A], then t1[B] = t2[B]".

Comment: For $A \to B$, this means "function", i,e, "A maps to B": "for each element (tuple?) of $A$ "there is an associated member (tuple) of B".

Comment: Hello. I worked out the answer and I'm about to answer my own question in a coherent and eloquent way just to clarify any confusion my poor way of framing the question might have stirred up amongst you.